# I can't export LaTeXiT equation to pdf with outlined fonts

Tags: errors, latexit

I recently updated to the new version of MacTeX and now LaTeXiT is giving me problems. I normally export the symbols as `"PDF with outlined fonts"` and just drag/drop them in Illustrator, but now when I try to do this with Greek letters, it gives me the following error message:

```
An error occured while trying to create the file with command:
/usr/local/bin/gs-noX11 -sDEVICE=eps2write -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dNOPLATFONTS -dNoOutputFonts=true /var/folders/82/cmrzmtbn3v5_b4l2980xrhmc0000gn/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.0/latexit-controller-0x106d650a0.pdf -c quit 2>|/var/folders/82/cmrzmtbn3v5_b4l2980xrhmc0000gn/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.0/export.aaF09gmo.log | /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf  -dSubsetFonts=false -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=100000 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100000 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress  - /var/folders/82/cmrzmtbn3v5_b4l2980xrhmc0000gn/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.0/latexit-controller-0x106d650a0-2.pdf 1>>/var/folders/82/cmrzmtbn3v5_b4l2980xrhmc0000gn/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.0/export.aaF09gmo.log 2>&1
```

when I look at the log file in the `/var/folders/82...` I see this:

```
Error: /undefined in ****
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1836   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1203/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

and I have absolutely no idea on how to interpret such error.

Comment: Same problem! Any suggestion, please?

Comment: The problem was solved after updating LaTeXiT

Comment: You are right, I updated to 2.8.1 and it works. Curiously, the "Check for updates" command in LaTeXit didn't find any update, had to do it manually. Thanks.

Comment: For me updating did not work, but upgrading ghostscript fixed it.